# AVFoundation set white balance values back to auto

Tags: objective-c, avfoundation

I'm building an app where I want to sometimes change the white balance using AVCaptureWhiteBalanceTemperatureAndTintValues, but then after a while I want to change the white balance back to be automatic. Is there any variable in AVFoundation that allows you to reset your temperature and tint values to auto?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. For anyone in the same boat, this is the line of code that I added:

```
[_videoDevice setWhiteBalanceMode:AVCaptureWhiteBalanceModeContinuousAutoWhiteBalance];
```